# Почему не работают другие action кроме index в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Захожу на главную страницу с контроллером Site, actionIndex, всё работает, как только перехожу на другую страницу с любым другим action в контроллере Site, то отображается 404 пустая страница. В конфиге прописан urlManager вот такой:

```
'urlManager' => [
          'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
          'showScriptName' => false,
          'enableStrictParsing' => true,
          'rules' => require(__DIR__ . '/routes.php'),
        ],
```

А в файле routers.php:

```
<?php

return [
    '<action>'=>'site/<action>',
    'company/<action>'=>'company/<action>',
    'moderation/<action>'=>'moderation/<action>',
    'login'=>'site/login',
    'logout'=>'site/logout',
    'moderation/user/emailsort'=>'moderation/user-emailsort',
    'moderation/reviews/deleted'=>'moderation/reviews-deleted',
    'moderation/reviews/approved'=>'moderation/reviews-approved',
    'moderation/queries/approved'=>'moderation/queries-approved',
    '' => 'site/index'
];
```

Если в конфиге, меняю "/" = > "site/index", на "/" => "site/login", то срабатывает actionLogin при заходе на главную, а если переходить на страницу /login, то такой конфиг "login" => "site/login", не работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Надо убрать параметр `enableStrictParsing` из конфига или поставить его в `false`.

Comment: Всё равно такая же проблема